# Android Dialog open before running Thread.sleep(1000) loop

Tags: android, multithreading, dialog

I am trying to open a `dialog` box before it runs a method in `dosubmit()` with a `Thread.sleep(1000)` loop that is checking for the result of a `RunnableFuture`.

It seems overriding the `setOnShowListener` is not working.

```
    private void dosubmitdialog(){
        mDialogloading = new ProgressDialog(mActivity);
        mDialogloading.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
        mDialogloading.setCancelable(false);
        mDialogloading.setMessage("Uploading data ...");
        mDialogloading.setOnShowListener(new DialogInterface.OnShowListener() {
            @Override
            public void onShow(DialogInterface dialog) {
                dosubmit();
            }
        });
        mDialogloading.show();
    }
```

What other approach can I use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using `Thread.sleep(1000)` use `Handler.postDelayed()` to call `dosubmit();` after 1000 as:

```
 public void onShow(DialogInterface dialog) {
    Handler handler=new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
       @Override
       public void run() {
            handler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null);
            dosubmit();
        }
    }, 1000);
   }
```

Comment: @K3NN3TH : do not use `Thread.sleep` because sleep method freeze UI Main Thread. try  using Handler